# How to resize a jQuery flot chart?

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a jQuery flot chart with this code:

```
$("table.statics").each(function() {
    var colors = [];
    $("table.statics thead th:not(:first)").each(function() {
        colors.push($(this).css("color"));
    });
    $(this).graphTable({
        series: 'columns',
        position: 'replace',
        height: '200px',
        colors: colors
    }, {
        xaxis: {
            tickSize: 1
        }
    });
});
```

This code is working fine, but now I want that the chart to resize when the window is resized.

How can i do this? I have the jquery.flot.resize.js included in my document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply delete the `"height:200px"` and give it `"height:40%"` or the amout you want.  
 In giving percent you ensure that the size is calculated new everytime when the window is resized.

Comment: It's not the height i want that resize but the width of the chart. But it's the same with the width i see, thnx! :)

Comment: this doesn't work for me, maybe the syntax is not right? @Maanstraat wrote `height: '200px',`, not `"height:200px"`

Answer (score 4):

Just add reference to jquery.flot.resize.js plugin that comes with flot charts and this is it.

From plugin documentation:

> Flot plugin for automatically redrawing plots when the placeholder
>   size changes, e.g. on window resizes.
>
> It works by listening for changes on the placeholder div (through the
>   jQuery resize event plugin) - if the size changes, it will redraw the
>   plot.

Could be downloaded from http://www.flotcharts.org/

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy fix - you just need to add one line to jquery.flot.pie.js:

```
var attempts = 0;
redraw = true; /* <--add this as line #281 */
while (redraw && attempts<redrawAttempts)
```

I got the solution from here:

https://github.com/flot/flot/commit/a2c38dc96489a217127c614879fa4dc9c8142f10#diff-0